# Controlling rotation of screen in iOS application

Tags: ios, xcode

How can I control the screen rotation in an iOS application?

I actually wants that my app should be in landscape mode only so that my UI should not get disturbed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in you project setting, Select orientation you want to support as mentioned in  below image.

[image]

Also you can override orientation related method of rootController of appDel.Window

Comment: You also need to override some orientation methods of you rootContoller. Check out my answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23992792/change-one-view-orientation-to-landscape/23993379#23993379